# How to print values of model joined through foreign key in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have one Model named as item as follows:

```
class Item(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 price = models.FloatField()
 bargainprice = models.FloatField(default=0)
 discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
 category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
 label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
 slug = models.SlugField()
 description = models.TextField()

 image = models.ImageField()
```

and  have a product page called " product.html" which shows the current product information as shown in image :[the product page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7hhk.png)

and i am getting all this data on product.html by the view as follows :

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
model = Item
template_name = "product.html"
```

and on product.html i am getting data by syntax :

```
         <span class="mr-1">
          <del>₹ {{ object.price }}</del>
        </span>
        <span>₹ {{ object.discount_price }}</span>
```

this is the one story which is working fine no issues till there **problem starts when i create this Bargain model below **

```
class Bargain(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
       settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
         )
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    bprice = models.FloatField()



    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
               fields=['item', 'user'], name='unique_user_item')
         ]
```

*let me explain the purpose of this bargain model. actually this model used to bargain the price of the product and it takes input price from user and updates to the bargain model with the following values User, Item and "bprice" which is new price of the product after bargaining  *

and i have succesfully created an object " Bargain object (3)" in the modal with values shown in image:[image of modal values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMFy9.png)

```
**so what i need - if user have bargained the price product.html show the bargain price which is "bprice" in the Bargain modal instead of product price in Item modal** of the respective user**
```

in order to achieve that i changed my itemView as follows :

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"
     
    def get_bargain(self, request):
      if request.user.is_authenticated():
         return Bargain.objects.filter(item=self.object, user=request.user).first()
```

and on product.html i am doing this :`<h1>This is the {{ view.get_bargain.bprice }}</h1>`

*but that gives me nothing *
more information - loggedin user admin

can anyone suggest me what i am doing wrong or any other method of doing that??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am not able to rectify what is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

there you can extend your view from `LoginRequiredMixin` if your view is restricted for logged in users. Then you can specify the context object name "item" as below.

```
class ItemDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"
    context_object_name = "item"
 
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
          return get_object_or_404(self.model, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

and in your template you can get all the bargains related with this item.
Just like.

```
{% if item.bargain %}
     <h1>This is the {{ item.bargain.first.bprice }}</h1>
{% else %}
     <h1> no bargain against this item </h1>
{% endif %}
```

Details:
`item` is the context item. and `item.bargain.first` gives you the access to first bargain item.

In your `app/urls.py`
you can put your url like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
   ....
   path('product/<int:pk>', ItemDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but there is an error KeyError at /product/6/
    'pk'

Comment: @AmaeraaSethi I updated the answer please check (specials the urls.py).